# Using any Docker image instead of AWS amazonlinux in an EC2 instance?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, docker

Amazon recommends its `amazonlinux` image when deploying a new service to a EC2 instance because it is optimized for their environment, or so the claim. I wonder if it's possible to use other images such a `node` image or a `python` one. Is there any real life drawbacks of using these instead of amazonlinux + node/python?

Comment: You can run any software you want on an EC2 instance, pretty much.  You're not limited to Amazon-branded OSes or container images.

Comment: One aspect to this is that the Amazon Linux 2 image comes preinstalled with software such as the Cloudwatch logs agent, SSM agent and the AWS CLI.  Having this already installed makes it easier to perform tasks involving other AWS infrastructure and services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The fact that all these AWS software comes preinstalled makes using other docker images not a good idea. I'll keep using amazonlinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to [Norman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551198/using-any-docker-image-instead-of-aws-amazonlinux-in-an-ec2-instance?noredirect=1#comment126461046_71551198) for his reply to my question who gave me the answer I was looking for.

Technically, you can run any Docker image in AWS EC2 instead of just the AWS `amazonlinux` image. However, the official `amazonlinux` comes with AWS tools and relevant software such as the Cloudwatch logs agent, SSM agent and the AWS CLI.

Said that, it's possible to [create your own CloudWatch agent in your own Docker image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights-build-docker-image.html).